# Accidental SAS cable removal

Tags: raid, sas, megaraid, jbod

We accidentally removed a SAS cable from an active AVAGO MegaRAID controller during a troubleshooting session. After we reconnected the SAS cable, all disks in the RAID6 disk array are reported as `Frn-Bad` and the virtual drive is gone.

We could now change all drives to "unconfigured good" and then create a new virtual drive, but there was still some (non-essential) data on the JBOD. Is it possible to recreate the disk configuration without losing data, or is the data irrecoverably lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: If you accidentally removed a SAS cable from your server then install `storcli` and run

```
storecli /call show
```

note the correct controller and enclosure and the nrun

```
#!/bin/bash
# Use your values from above
CONTROLLER=
ENCLOSURE=

storcli /c$CONTROLLER /e$ENCLOSURE /sall set good
storcli /c$CONTROLLER /fall show

echo -n "Import all foreign drives? [y/n]" 
read yno

case $yno in
    [yY] | [yY][Ee][Ss] )
        storcli /c$CONTROLLER /fall import
        ;;
    *) echo "Skipping import"
        ;;
esac
```

---

When you disconnected the SAS cable, the controller noticed that all drives where gone and therefore potentially in a bad state. That's why you get `Bad`. Also, the drives were potentially new and not yet included in your RAID setup, that's why you get `Frn` and as a result `Frn-Bad`.

In order to fix this, you first need to mark all drives as `UGood` (unknown, but good). The simplest way is to use `storcli` ([download from LSI](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-sas-9380-4i4e#downloads)). First look up all drives with

```
storcli /call show
```

The `/call` will look for all controllers, but you might as well use `/cX` for a specific one. All `Frn-Bad` drives will reside in a single enclosure, e.g.

```
8:1  | drive information .... | Frn-Bad | ...
8:13 | drive information .... | Frn-Bad | ...
8:14 | drive information .... | Frn-Bad | ...
8:23 | drive information .... | Frn-Bad | ...
```

The common number in front of the colon is the enclosure. Call `storcli` again and use the enclosure number to verify that you really have the right drives at hand:

```
storcli /call /e8 /sall show
```

Now set all those drives to good

```
storcli /call /e8 /sall set good
```

This will mark the drives as unknown and good. The MEGARaid controller saves the configuration on the hard drives. You can show it with

```
storcli /c0 /fall show
```

and then import it with

```
storcli /c0 /fall import
```

It should take less than a minute to import the drives.

Answer (score 0):

It could be useful to perform this check:

https://www.servethehome.com/fixing-drive-labeled-foreign-lsi-avago-sas-controller/

Unfortunately I hope the configuration was not fully removed. If you able to scan the foreign configuration, you should still be able to enable the Raid Array.

But I cannot guarantee this as you have already created a new Virtual drive with those disks.

Comment: *"But I cannot guarantee this as you have already created a new Virtual drive with those disks. "* We haven't (yet).